# Pre-select value in edit view in CakePHP when using virtual fields

Tags: php, html, cakephp, model-view-controller

I have a simple edit form that pre-select selected values without any issues. But there is one select input field that contains objects from the class `ContactPerson`. I want to show the `prename` and the `lastname` in the view so I created a virtual field called `fullname`. The problem is that CakePHP does not pre-select it when I open the view.

ContactPerson class:

```
id
prename
lastname
fullname (virtual field for prename . " " . lastname)
```

Edit Method in the Controller:

```
$contact_persons = $this->Product->ContactPerson->find('list', array('fields' => array('id','fullname'), 'order' => array('fullname' => 'asc'), 'conditions' => array("not" => array ( "fullname" => ' '))));
$this->set(compact('contact_persons'));
```

View:

```
echo "<div class='control-group'>";
echo $this->Form->label('contact_person_id', 'Contact Person:', 'control-label');
echo "<div class='controls'>";
echo $this->Form->input('contact_person_id', array('class' => 'select-input', 'empty' => 'Choose Contact Person', 'options' => $contact_persons));
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
```

Due to the fact that I used a virtual field for ContactPersons, it does not pre-select it in the edit view. How can I tell CakePHP that a particular object has to be pre-selected when using virtual fields?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your ContactPerson Model:

```
public $displayField = 'fullname';
```

Cake uses the display field to determine which field to use to populate selects generated by the form helper off of list type finds. If you don't set a displayField it will use the id.

-- For a field pulled from a related model

Not tested but I think you should be able to set the displayField on the fly for your Product model - which is the one you are using in this scenario.

Add the following to your controller:

```
$this->Product->displayField = 'fullname';
```

Just before you do your find. You need to do this in the controller method as you may have other methods for Product which don't pull in data from ContactPerson.

Comment: Thanks Simon, but that did not fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry - I just noticed you are pulling in to Product from a related model. Updated answer.